# How to changed cursor when you drag object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

css

```
.draggable,
.draggable * {
    cursor: url('img/arrowHand.png'), auto;
}
```

js

```
$('body').on('dragstart', function () {
    $('body').addClass('draggable');
});
$('body').on('dragend', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('draggable');
});
```

The class is assigned, the cursor image is loaded, but used the  standard cursor when you drag the object. What needs to change?

Comment: the css of the dragged element

Answer (score 1):

Just add this style

```
body.draggable {
   cursor : move;
}
```

See the full example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

Answer (score 0):

You can see demo also you dont need javascript code for cursor

[JSFiddle Demo](http://JSFiddle%20Demo)

Answer (score 0):

> Just add this to your draggable class, then it works fine

```html
 cursor : move;
```